# How can I show a label with select2 in bootstrap 3 form-horizontal mode?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Please see this jfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/3wZ4y/2/

```
    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="select02">Select 02</label>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
        <input type="hidden" id="select02" style="width: 100%" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

For some reason I can't force the Label to appear to the left of the select2 dropdown control. Instead it appears on the right!

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/fc1qevem/1/

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="skill" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Skill</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input id="select02" style="width: 100%"></input>
    </div>
</div>
```